# The Ubuntu filesystem became read-only and I can't boot into it anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

This has occurred twice now, in Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 19.04, I ran both alongside windows 10 on Dual Boot.

I had Ubuntu 18.04, I was moving data to my external hard drive and a file couldn't be moved, when I cancelled it I noticed that all my folders on Ubuntu have become read-only, I change the permissions of my home folder and it was fixed. But after a reboot, I couldn't boot into Ubuntu anymore. It was in the bios but I got an error while booting into it.

I used a live boot on usb with Ubuntu 19.04 and tried to fix it (I was told the reason might be an update from windows or because of fast startup so I stopped both, but it happened again) and it didn't work so I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 instead since I was told the reason might be that my system is corrupt.

And now after a day of using Ubuntu 19.04, the same problem has occurred again, what can I do to fix it? I thought about formatting my external hard drive, but if that fails I'd lose all my data for no reason, so I thought I should ask first.

Edit: the log files var/log/syslog  and dmesg respectively.

https://pastebin.com/k3dSw4CH

https://pastebin.com/yMQa1HBc

Comment: Use a LiveUSB to boot, mount your HDD, and check /var/log/syslog and dmesg for useful errror messages before the system went read-only. Linux systems jump to read-only to protect the system when they encounter errors (usually hardware errors). It's a setting in /etc/fstab (don't change it). After checking the logs, look up how to run a SMART test on both hard drives.

Comment: @user535733 I did that, the short Smart test on both gave Ok as an assessment, as for the files, I'm having a hard time understanding the problems.

Comment: What about the logs?

Comment: @user535733 That's what I meant by files earlier, they were hardly understandable, all I could get out of syslog was the time and some things I did before the problems started. As for dmesg, I really didn't understand its contents at all.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant output from your logs. Without real data, we cannot offer considered advice.

Comment: @user535733 I'm not sure which parts are most necessary, can I paste the files onto pastebin and link them here?

Comment: That is a great idea. Do it.